# has chrome eliminated the classic avatar menu?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profile, avatar

Like many web developers, I maintain numerous profiles in Google Chrome so as to test web applications.  When doing these tests, it is essential to rapidly determine which profile I am in when interacting with Chrome.  I depended on the classic Chrome avatar menu to signal the current profile.  For months now, Chrome has defaulted to a newer profile menu that only showed the current user's name in text (no avatar image).  Until today, it was possible to go back to using the classic avatar menu by navigating to chrome://flags and then disabling Enable New Profile Management System.  Now, doing this has no effect. I was wondering if perhaps there is some other way to enable the classic avatar menu so that my web development tests can proceed as before.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately a design decision by Google, and it looks like they're sticking to it. When it initially happened, I (like you) set the flag & was able to use legacy icons, but as of this morning the flag itself has been disabled.

Further reading (follow the links to related issues): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=512699

I have no idea how much good it will do, but starring the issue and leaving a polite, detailed comment on issue #451920 is a good place to start.